# How to add zstd and lz4 algorithm to tar on MacOS?

Tags: macos, tar, lz4, zstd

So my tar version on MacOS doesn't seem to support the zstd or lz4 algorithms, and I am unsure how to update tar or add support for it. My Ubuntu's tar version seems to have support for zstd.

Comment: I think it already implemented. man tar. for compress. --zstd. for decompress, tar x is good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can use zstd with older versions of tar.

```
tar cvf - "directory" | zstd > "archive.tar.zstd"
```

You also might want to check out [gnu-tar](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gnu-tar) from [homebrew](https://brew.sh/).